# How to make two CSS shapes appear in a grid cell?

Tags: html, css

I have used CSS to make a grid with two columns.

I want to make the second cell in the grid display two rectangles - one red and one green.

My first attempt was the code at the bottom of this question. This makes a red rectangle in the second cell of the grid and a green rectangle in the third cell of the grid.

In my second attempt I tried to combine the red and green rectangles into one item "rectangles"

```
.rectangles {
  height: 50px;
  width: 205px;
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
  height: 50px;
  width: 105px;
  background-color: #66ff33;
}
```

The second attempt just made the first (red) rectangle disappear.

Maybe I have to make a grid within a grid to contain the red rectangle and green rectangle separately. This seems like a messy approach. Is there any better way?

This is my first attempt below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1ft;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 1px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.item1 {
  font-size: 10px
}

.rectangleRed {
  height: 50px;
  width: 205px;
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

.rectangleGreen {
  height: 50px;
  width: 105px;
  background-color: #66ff33;
}
  
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">lorem ipsum<div>  
  <div class="rectangleRed"></div>
  <div class="rectangleGreen"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1ft? I think you have that wrong

Comment: @Paulie_D Now I think about it 1ft is pretty weird. I got it from a tutorial. It wont affect the rectangles, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}
.grid-container div {
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
}
.item1 { font-size: 10px; }
.pre { display: inline; }
.rectangleRed {
  height: 50px;
  width: 205px;
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
}
.rectangleGreen {
  height: 50px;
  width: 105px;
  background-color: #66ff33;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">lorem ipsum</div>  
  <div>
    <pre class="rectangleRed"></pre>
    <pre class="rectangleGreen"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or possibly:

```
.rectangleRed {
   height: 50px;
   width: 205px;
   background-color: #ff1a1a;
   float: left; 
   margin-right: 4px;
 }
 .rectangleGreen {
   height: 50px;
   width: 105px;
   background-color: #66ff33;
   float: left; 
 }
```

Comment: That's it! So it's the addition of 'float: left;' which allows the two rectangles to appear directly left/right of each other

Comment: On second thought it appears to be the addition of the "pre" block that allows the <div> to contain multiple rectangles